# Calling flickr api using jquery ajax - IE Dilemma

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, flickr

wondering if anyone can help me out. I'm trying to call the flickr api.
I'm using the following code, which works great in everything but Internet Explorer. Does anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? It's not even making the network call.

```
get_service_base : function(){
        return "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method";
    },
    get_api_key : function(){
        return "api_key=1234567890-myapikey";
    },

    get_photoset : function (id, callback)
    {
    var base_url =this.get_service_base()+'=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&'+this.get_api_key()+'&photoset_id='+id+'&format=json&nojsoncallback=1';
    jQuery.getJSON(base_url,{}, function(data)
    {
        callback(data);
    });
```

Any help mucu appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could not get this working in IE 8 - so ending up using a callback and all was good

Changed URL to 
return "http://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?jsoncallback=?&method";

And took out 
nojsoncallback=1